# Multiple enumeration of IEnumerable

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I know IEnumerable has been discussed several times here but I couldn't find the answer to my specific question so I'm bringing it up as a new question.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> testList = new List<string> {"Test", "Test1", "Test1"};
        IEnumerable<string> filtered = testList.Where(x => x == "Test1");

        DoSomeWork(filtered);
        DoSomeMoreWork(filtered);
    }

    public static void DoSomeWork(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("do some work");
        }
    }

    public static void DoSomeMoreWork(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("do some more work");
        }
    }
```

Am I right, that this causes not only the two items in "filtered" to iterate two times but actually the items in "testList"? So, considering that "testList" was a big list with 10000 items and "filtered" reduces it to 10 items, it would be more clever to make "filtered" a list (aka use var and just append ToList() at the end)

**EDIT:** 
That's the most embarrassing question I ever asked here. I knew it would be bad to iterate an IQueryable for example because this would result in fetching the data twice from the DB. However I wasn't exactly sure about in memory lists. I would delete the question if I could ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is ultimatly inherit from IEnumrable check this

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

One more thing you can create list of IEnurable using the following constructor avaialble

```
public List(
    IEnumerable<T> collection
)
```

**EDIT**

The derivedi.e filtered list is get iterated twice by the both methods but append .ToList() method at the end .

```
IEnumerable<string> filtered = testList.Where(x => x == "Test1").ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the question is. Will DoSomeWork() and DoSomeMoreWork() both cause iterating the big list or will they only iterate the subset.

Comment: Better to use .ToArray that ToList for this use: array's are somewhat more efficient, but most importantly, they do not allow add/remove, avoiding unnecessary flexibility (thus avoiding confusion and bugs).

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that using `List<>` a lot in linq code is generally a code smell: it's almost never the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

The big list will be reiterated twice. To check that this really happens change your query to:

```
List<string> testList = new List<string> { "Test", "Test1", "Test1" };
IEnumerable<string> filtered = from t in testList
                               where t == "Test1"
                               select t;
```

If you then set a breakpoint on the 'where t == "Test1" part, you will see that the debugger hits this line for both the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The big list will be reiterated twice. if you don't want it, you can "materialize" the restriction.

```
var filtered = testList.Where(x => x == "Test1").ToList();
```

And there are many answers that tell you this. You should have searched better :-)

Answer (score 0):

> it would be more clever to make "filtered" a list (aka use var and just append ToList() at the end)

Yes, especially in terms of Linq-To-Entities etc.

Returning an `IEnumerable` with linq allows for differed execution. When you do append `ToList()` to the end, your list is returned right there.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx